# Local Object Variables Thread Safety In Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I know that primitive local variables are thread safe because they are allocated in stack and it is unique for each thread.

What about object variables: are they thread safe in local scope.

I have the following pseudocode:

```
private void myMethod(int myInt) {

    final Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Put some values into map.
    ...
    // Get some values from map.   
}
```

In this case do i need to change the HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap or is it already thread safe?

Comment: As long as you don't leak the reference to another thread, it's safe.

Comment: What do you mean by leaking the reference?

Comment: I mean passing it a method or field that allows another thread to access it concurrently.

Comment: Each thread calling pong() creates its own Map object, and this object is never shared between threads, so yes, it's safe. Unless of course you start storing the map reference in a field of an object that multiple threads share, and the map thus become used by several threads. That would be leaking the reference to other threads.

Comment: Only class level variables can be used concurrently. Method variables - can't

Comment: @JaySmith That's pretty inaccurate. A local variable can become a class variable, or be passed straight into a new thread, or be passed into another method that does that does the same.

Comment: If you assign local variable to class level variable then it is not thread safe. What is inaccurate?

Comment: @JaySmith You can share a method local final variable with a thread without declaring it in class level - clearly  it is a way to use a "method variable" concurently. The final means only the reference is immutable, the state of that object is mutable.

Comment: There is no reason to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` at all. Making every code “thread safe” without having an actual multi-threaded scenario to support, makes no sense. It will slow down your application, but likely still be broken when you start using it with multiple threads, as just using a `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn’t protect you from semantic problems of concurrent modifications. More than often, application specific access protocols are sufficient for a correct program, without the need for attempts of implementing thread safety at the lower levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as any other Thread does not read or write this variable you don't need to worry.
The synchronization is needed when one thread is writing and second is reading a variable. In case of no synchronization the reading thread can see stale value.

Java concurrency is very broad topic, it is hard to learn it without any background like reading a book first. My favorite book in this topic is: "Java concurrency in practice", I advise you to read it first, then come back here and ask if you will have more questions.